# Free cross platform 2D graphical game engine

Tags: c++

Are there any **C/C++** free cross-platform **2D oriented** graphical game engines (for isometric game)?
I'm expecting following features from engine:

- Window creation
- OpenGL context creation and initialization
- Resource management
- Animated sprites
- Particle systems

I've considered OGRE (seems to be 3D oriented), Irrlicht (much more than just graphical engine, and also 3D oriented), SDL (only low-level functions, no resource loading/management).

Could you please advise anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it's not a full-featured game engine, [SFML](http://sfml-dev.org/) might suit your needs. Apart from window and OpenGL context creation it also provides 2D sprite functionality. Sprite animation and particle systems are not available out-of-the box but should be easy enough to implement on top of the existing features. Someone apparently already implemented an [OGRE-like particle system](http://www.sfml-dev.org/wiki/en/projects/particle_system) in SFML.

SFML is distributed under the zlib/png license, which might or might not meet your definition of "free".

Comment: +1 It works really well, and you can even integrate it into the major gui frameworks, Gtk, Qt, or wxWidgets.